# Creating Visual Studio project from existing C files, header files and makefile

Tags: c, visual-studio, makefile

I have a C file which depends on 5 header files in its own folder, and also depends on some header files outside of its directory - but their path is included in a makefile.
For now I'm using the makefile for compiling, but I want to move to visual studio for doing that.
In SlickEdit I know that I can create .vpj file for this purpose - but I don't know what is the equivalent for visual studio.

Can you please tell me how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Consider using File > New > Project From Existing Code.

Comment: @HansPassant, How do you use it when you have dependencies from other directories?

Comment: Use that wizard as far as it will take you, it doesn't cover all possible cornercases.  Add additional files in wonky places with Project > Add Existing Item.  You might want to spend an hour to click around in the VS user interface, this stuff is supposed to be discoverable.  Press F1 if something is murky.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio 2017, then you don't even need a project file, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/develop-code-in-visual-studio-without-projects-or-solutions?view=vs-2017